# Primary Key violations from multithreaded counter implemented in EF5

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I'm trying to implement a consistent multi-reader-writer counter using EF5 Code First, and I'm encountering concurrency exceptions (which I expected), but I'm also encountering Primary Key constraint violations, which I did not expect.  This *only* happens if the counter is **created** by the code; if it is already existing, the counting takes place as expected.

Here is the code I'm using (with debugging code as well):

```
public class EFCounter
{
    private static int UpdateExceptionCount = 0;
    private const int StartValue = 1000001;

    public int CreateOrIncrement(Guid counterId)
    {
        using (var context = new EFCounterContext("MsSqlViewModel"))
        {
            if (context.Counters.Any(cntr => cntr.CounterId == counterId) == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    context.Counters.Add(
                        new Counter
                            {
                                CounterId = counterId,
                                Value = StartValue
                            }
                        );
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return StartValue;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //fall through
                }
            }
            var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext;
            var counter = context.Counters.First(cntr => cntr.CounterId == counterId);
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    lock (this)
                    {
                        counter.Value += 1;
                        objectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
                        return counter.Value;
                    }
                }
                catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException ex)
                {
                    objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, counter);
                }
                catch (UpdateException ex)
                {
                    var ueCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref UpdateExceptionCount);
                    objectContext.Detach(counter);
                    counter = context.Counters.First(cntr => cntr.CounterId == counterId);
                    Console.WriteLine("UpdateExceptions: {0}", ueCount);
                }

            } while (true);
        }
    }
}

public class Counter
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid CounterId { get; set; }
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm simply using `Parallel.For` to invoke it:

```
EFCounter counter1 = new EFCounter();
EFCounter counter2 = new EFCounter();

Guid counterId = Guid.NewGuid();
Parallel.For(
    1,
    10,
    i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1: {0}", counter1.CreateOrIncrement(counterId));
            Console.WriteLine("2: {0}", counter2.CreateOrIncrement(counterId));
        }
    );
```

For reference, the connection string:

```
<add name="MsSqlViewModel" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ESRaffleViewModels;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

Here is the output of a representative run on my machine; I've never actually had a run complete where I had UpdateExceptions show up:

```
1: 1000001
2: 1000002
UpdateExceptions: 1
1: 1000003
UpdateExceptions: 2
2: 1000004
UpdateExceptions: 3
1: 1000005
UpdateExceptions: 4
2: 1000006
UpdateExceptions: 5
UpdateExceptions: 6
UpdateExceptions: 7
UpdateExceptions: 8
UpdateExceptions: 9
UpdateExceptions: 10
UpdateExceptions: 11
UpdateExceptions: 12
UpdateExceptions: 13
UpdateExceptions: 14
UpdateExceptions: 15
UpdateExceptions: 16
UpdateExceptions: 17
UpdateExceptions: 18
UpdateExceptions: 19
UpdateExceptions: 20
UpdateExceptions: 21
UpdateExceptions: 22
UpdateExceptions: 23
UpdateExceptions: 24
UpdateExceptions: 25
UpdateExceptions: 26
UpdateExceptions: 27
UpdateExceptions: 28
UpdateExceptions: 29
UpdateExceptions: 30
UpdateExceptions: 31
UpdateExceptions: 32
UpdateExceptions: 33
UpdateExceptions: 34
UpdateExceptions: 35
UpdateExceptions: 36
UpdateExceptions: 37
UpdateExceptions: 38
UpdateExceptions: 39
UpdateExceptions: 40
UpdateExceptions: 41
UpdateExceptions: 42
UpdateExceptions: 43
UpdateExceptions: 44
UpdateExceptions: 45
UpdateExceptions: 46
UpdateExceptions: 47
UpdateExceptions: 48
UpdateExceptions: 49
UpdateExceptions: 50
UpdateExceptions: 51
UpdateExceptions: 52
UpdateExceptions: 53
UpdateExceptions: 54
UpdateExceptions: 55
UpdateExceptions: 56
UpdateExceptions: 57
UpdateExceptions: 58
UpdateExceptions: 59
UpdateExceptions: 60
UpdateExceptions: 61
UpdateExceptions: 62
UpdateExceptions: 63
UpdateExceptions: 64
UpdateExceptions: 65
UpdateExceptions: 66
UpdateExceptions: 67
UpdateExceptions: 68
UpdateExceptions: 69
UpdateExceptions: 70
UpdateExceptions: 71
UpdateExceptions: 72
UpdateExceptions: 73
UpdateExceptions: 74
UpdateExceptions: 75
UpdateExceptions: 76
UpdateExceptions: 77
UpdateExceptions: 78
UpdateExceptions: 79
UpdateExceptions: 80
UpdateExceptions: 81
UpdateExceptions: 82
UpdateExceptions: 83
UpdateExceptions: 84
UpdateExceptions: 85
UpdateExceptions: 86
UpdateExceptions: 87
UpdateExceptions: 88
UpdateExceptions: 89
UpdateExceptions: 90
UpdateExceptions: 91
UpdateExceptions: 92
UpdateExceptions: 93
UpdateExceptions: 94
UpdateExceptions: 95
UpdateExceptions: 96
UpdateExceptions: 97
UpdateExceptions: 98
UpdateExceptions: 99
UpdateExceptions: 100
```

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: A database is meant to serialize database transactions.  We use parallel multithreaded frameworks like asp.net because concurrency is always an issue.  This is an exercise in why you should not use parallel operations when you don't need to.

Comment: My need to handle parallelism is not the question here.  I'm simply curious why my *implementation* isn't behaving as I'd expect it to.

Comment: I gave you the answer to this below. lock on something that both threads can see.  Italicizing "implementation" doesn't change the fact that your experiment is an exercise in futility.  You are taking concurrency handling away from the database, and <I>implementing</I> it incorrectly

Comment: How am I supposed to lock on something that both threads can see when the threads are running on different machines?  And how am I taking concurrency handling away from the database by using a `lock` statement in my code?

Comment: You use the database as your serialization (locking/unlocking) mechanism if you are using separate processes.  By not using the database for concurrency, you are taking concurrency handling away from the database.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the reason I'm getting concurrency exceptions is because I'm running these as threads within a single process, rather than in separate processes?

Comment: No. You will get the same problems if you run in separate processes.  If you were going to run in the same process, then you could get by with fixing your lock(this) error.  The only solution is to use the database to do concurrency!

Answer (score -1):

locking on (this) is not exclusive to both instances of your EFCounter, so that is essentially useless.  You need a static object.

You need to use the database to handle database concurrency.

Comment: Locking on `this` is not supposed to be exclusive to both instances - I'm designing this as a proof of concept for a distributed service, and happened to pick EF to try.  Would you mind pointing out some of the "dirtier" things you see in actual comments on the question?

Comment: if the lock is not exclusive, it is useless.  Why are you doing the lock if you aren't actually preventing two threads from doing the same thing at the same time?

Comment: As I said - I'm designing this as a **distributed** service.  The lock is to aid concurrency when running this, for instance, as a singleton.  The test case I provided is designed to emulate having 2 instances of the service running and concurrently updating the same table.

Comment: bolding "distributed" does not make the lock(this) do anything in the code above.